# Django DateField not saving the selected date from picker

Tags: python, django, datetime, web, datepicker

I have a django model with some models.DateField and a default value.
The forms.py looks like this:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class AddNewCar(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label ="Imagine Masina", required=False)
    vigneta = forms.DateField(label ="Valabilitate Rovinieta", widget=DateInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('image',)
```

The models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(Users, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    vigneta     = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, blank = False)
```

And in views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = AddNewCar(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        m = form.save()
        m.owner = request.user
        m.save()
        return redirect("home")
```

The problem is when I submit the form, don't give any errors but the date that's saved is not the selected one, is the default date.

Comment: Did you try: `fields = ('image', 'vigneta')`?

Comment: Yeas! It's not working!